# How to access a device connected in another switch, which is in another subnet

Tags: switch, subnet, printer

How are you? I hope you're doing well.

As you can see by the tittle im facing a problem trying to access a device, a printer to be more specific, in another swithc which is in another subnet. This is my first week in the new job and first thing they told me to do is make the printer accessible for the computers connected on one of the switches.They have two different internet links, one in each switch.

The **Switch A** is distributing with the IP 192.168.1.x
And the **Switch B** is distributing the IP 20.20.0.x

The switches 3com layer 3. Theres any chance to make this happend only using the swithes? Thanks in advance

[Heres a image of network layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6QDX.png)

Comment: Are the two network switches close enough to run a cable between them?

Comment: Yes. They are in the same rack.

Comment: You can connect the two switches together and enable routing between them. I don’t know the exact syntax for 3com, but if you migrate this question to the Network Engineering SE site, there are lots of people there who can help you with the details.

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t make a VPN tunnel you can use a less costly solution;

- Multihome the printer by using another NIC inside it connected to the second network.

If no option exist to have two NIC on the printer then use a small USB to RJ45 printserver adapter for the printer if you can use a USB on it while the NIC work.
It will make of use the USB port